# Call animation method when UItextField.enabled changes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a set of UITextFields which are enabled or disabled based on an if function (basically only allows 2 to be filled in, then the others are disabled).

I've got 2 methods to fade the background of the UItextFieldFade in and Fade out.

I want the animation to run every time the enabled property of the UITextField changes but don't really know how to track the actual change.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an observer to the text field:

```
[_textField addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"enabled" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

You should implement this method:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *) context;
```

Where you handle the value change of the "enabled" property.

Documentation: [Key value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could anyone please explain this a little bit to me? I'm trying to find some documentation or examples to walk me through what's actually going on when using the observer but there doesn seem to be much out there.

Comment: I edited the answer and added a link that explains it pretty well.

Comment: One follow up question, If my UITextField is enabled (1) and there's a method that just sets it to 1 again (generic for all textfields, evaluates all at one time), the Observer fires even though there's no change. Is this normal?

Comment: OK I used NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld and compared the old and new value in the new method. Thanks again for the help.